# Show Multiple Weights

Tags: modeling

[image]

I would like to see multiple weights and not just the active bone why in weight painting mode you can only see 1 at a time it's kinda annoying clicking back and fourth just to compare is there a modifier or something to fix this?

Comment: And how would you expect that to work?

Comment: good idea, non active weight paint could be pink and yellow instead of red and green.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot see simultaneously two weight influences. I don't know how that can be possible to see on the same mesh as they may overlap.

Though, even if that does not answer the question, you can use the "multi paint" option in the drawing toolshelf.

[image]

As indicated in the tool tip, that allows to paint over the selected bones and maintaining their relative influence.

So the paint will affect these bones so that they stay relatively the same between them but change relatively to the other (non selected) bones.

But doing that you cannot compare them, as, as you can see the color shown here is homogeneous.

What you can do, though is opening two views, one with your model, one with UV image editor and proceed to an opengl rendering:

[image]

Comment: this didn't really answer my question but its good to know what you said so thanks

Comment: I was trying to show what was possible with multiple bones selection. But short answer can be "no, you can not do it". But as @DuarteFarrajotaRamos said: "how would you expect that to work?"